# Return only emitted items from an Observable

Tags: java-8, rx-java

I want to get emitted items from an Observable stream.

I can do this in Collection streams with the following code:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
String result = items.stream().filter(i -> i.equals("a")).findFirst().orElse("");
```

I want to do the same thing with RxJava Observable. I tried this but it returns an `Observable<String>` not a `String`.

```
Observable<String> result2 = Observable.from(items).filter(i -> i.equals("a")).firstOrDefault("");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to get a `BlockingObservable<T>` which is synchronous and against the push model of reactive programming. See the comment in the javadoc ([Link to Blocking Operations](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators)):

> BlockingObservable is a variety of Observable that provides blocking operators. It can be useful for testing and demo purposes, but is generally inappropriate for production applications (if you think you need to use a BlockingObservable this is usually a sign that you should rethink your design).

So the solution to your problem looks like:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
String result = Observable.from(items).filter(i -> i.equals("a"))
                          .toBlocking().firstOrDefault("");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Interesting. So, if we need direct access to emitted items then we have to leave asynchronous model.